# multiple peripherals though a single USB type C

Tags: power-supply, usb, switch-mode-power-supply, usb-hub

I'm trying to build a TV set-up box composed of several peripherals such as:  computer(raspberry compute module), wireless audio transmitter and a DSP each with various power requirements.  I would like to power them using a single USB Type C connector. Is there any off the shelf solution for this? I'm not familiar with the USB protocol but it seems that the power must be negotiated somehow and I'm wondering how can I do that(i.e. do I need to program it, do I need to create a kind of internal USB hub with USB connectors for each compoenent?).

[0] Power requirements

```
****Raspbery Compute module***********************************
 3V3 and 1V8.                                                *
 3V3 comes up at exactly the same time or before 1V8         *
 aprox 700mA along with the Lan chip                         *
--------------------------------------------------------------

*****External DSP********
5VDC SMPS aprox 300mA ***
*************************

********Wireless Transmitter ******************************************************
source 3V3 voltage  | min 3.135 V | typ 3.3 V | max 3.4651 V |comment 3.3V ±5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
source 3V3 active supply current| typ 850 mA | max 1100 mA |comment Design for 1.5 A peak
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source 3V3 supply ripple| max 50 mV |comment: Peak to peak
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source 1V2 voltage | min 1.14 V | typ 1.2 V | max 1.26 V | comment: 1.2 V ±5%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source: 1V2 active supply current | typ 165 mA | max 200 mA
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
source: 1V2 supply ripple| max 25 mV| comment: Peak to peak
```

Comment: Are you over or under 15W? Also, who is supplying the power?

Answer (score 0):

Type C is 900mA basic and 1.5 - 5 A negotiated. 
The standards for negotiation are readily available in the Rev 2.0 spec. 
Suggest you start [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/).

If your device is supplied by a single Type C then you could negotiate without an internal Hub. You could of course have multiple USB endpoints in your device requiring a Hub, but you still only need to negotiate power over the single USB Type C.